# fujixerox‑CP105b paper jams on second page

Tags: paper

My daughter has this printer which has a paper jam on the 2nd page every time. The first page prints smoothly but the 2nd page jams at the back of the printer ?

We have had 2 replacements and they all do the same

Any suggestions please ?

Comment: Do you keep using the same paper?

Comment: I suggest you try a different brand or model printer.

Comment: have you tries fanning out the paper before loading?

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving a jam on the second page you are likely to be printing with A4 when the printer is set to Letter. You need to go into the printer driver settings to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I **changed the paper size** on the second one and now it prints fine.

I've just got a replacement for mine back from repair and it seemed to jam differently to before. The first one jammed at the back. The new one, even on a single page, would print the first page and then have an error because it cant grab a second sheet, even though the second sheet is not required. I used the Fuji Xerox paper and reflex.